# JQuery .show() function couldn't be completed. Is it possible?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$("#someLoaderImage").show("fade", "slow", function () {
  console.log("completed");
  .
  .
  .
  $("#someLoaderImage").hide("fade","slow");
});
```

and sometimes it is not writing `completed` on console and is stuck on showing. It is not going further in the execution. This happens only in Internet Explorer and not always (FF and Chrome okay). Has anyone met the same issue?

EDIT: the problem does not occur if Developers Tool are turned on.

Comment: What version of IE are you using ?

Comment: Show us the rest of the code. Any errors on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Give #someLoaderImage a position:relative; in css. This seems to fix issues like these in Internet Explorer.

Comment: it already has position: fixed... Should I change to relative?

Comment: Actually, what are you trying to achieve with this code? Since you're going for a fade in, why don't you just use 

`$('#someLoaderImage').fadeIn('slow', function(){
 console.log('completed');
});`

Comment: I'm maintaining existing code, I don't understand many things. Is it possible to use `fade` as an argument of `.show()`?

Comment: It's definitely not the norm, if I were you I'd change it by adding fadeIn, I'm pretty sure it will work as intended with the code I posted above.

Just like you use fadeIn() you can use fadeOut().